# Converting a list of dicts to wiki-format

Tags: python, dictionary, confluence

I have a list of dicts that looks like this (might look like this, I really have no idea upfront what data they contain):

```
data = [
  {'k1': 'v1-a', 'k2': 'v2-a', 'k3': 'v3-a'},
  {'k1': 'v1-b', 'k3': 'v3-b'},
  {'k1': 'v1-c', 'k2': 'v2-c', 'k3': 'v3-c'},
  {'k1': 'v1-d', 'k2': 'v2-d', 'k3': 'v3-d'}
]
```

The goal is to make it into a string that looks like this:

```
||k1||k2||k3||
|v1-a|v2-a|v3-a|
|v1-b||v3-b|
|v1-c|v2-c|v3-c|
|v1-d|v2-d|v3-d|
```

This is for the [confluence wiki format](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-wiki-markup-251003035.html#ConfluenceWikiMarkup-Tables).

The problem in itself is not that complicated, but the solution I come up with is so ugly that I almost don't want to use it.

What I got currently is this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
// data = ...
df = DataFrame.from_dict(data).fillna('')
body = '||{header}||\n{data}'.format(
  header='||'.join(df.columns.values.tolist()),
  data='\n'.join(['|{}|'.format('|'.join(i)) for i in df.values.tolist()])
)
```

Which isn't just ugly, it depends on pandas, which is huge (I don't want to depend on this library just for this)!
The solution above would work without pandas if there was a good way of getting the list of headers, and list of list of values from the dict. But `python 2` does't guaranty dict order, so I can't count on `.values()` giving me the correct info.

Is there anything in `itertools` or `collections` I've been missing out of?

Comment: can you clarify on what you mean by pandas being huge? Is it slower than expected or something? Pandas tends to be pretty speedy

Comment: There's nothing quite that straightforward, but you might have more readable solutions, depending on the variability of your keys (headers).  How much variability do you have in the supplied fields?  For instance, are you guaranteed that *some* dict will have *all* of the keys?  If so, you can glean your headers from the longest dict.  Will each dict have the first key, or the last?  These can help with constructing an ordered list.  If none of those, you will likely need to apply something like a topological sort on the partial orderings.

Comment: Added a comment.. It is awesome. But I don't want to depend on it just to solve this little problem

Comment: @Prune: nah.. The inputdicts are dynamic. I have no idea what they will contain :(

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Python 3 and 2.7. Try it: https://repl.it/repls/VividMediumturquoiseAlbino

```
all_keys = sorted({key for dic in data for key in dic.keys()})

header = "||" + "||".join(all_keys) + "||"

lines = [header]

for row in data:
    elems_on_row = [row.get(key, "") for key in all_keys]
    current_row = "|" + "|".join(elems_on_row) + "|"
    lines.append(current_row)

wikistr = "\n".join(lines)
print(wikistr)
```

Comment: Minor typo in the construction of the header line. It should be two || for joining the keys.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in pure Python is to walk the list  and therefore every dictionary twice.
In the first run you can collect all distinct keys and in the second run you can build your wiki formatted string output.

Let's start by collecting the keys where we can use a set as storage:

```
keys = set()
for dict_ in data:
    keys.update(set(dict_.keys())

keys = sorted(keys)
```

Now that we have the set of unique keys, we can run through the list again for the output:

```
wiki_output = ''

wiki_output = '||' + '||'.join(keys) + '||' 

for dict_ in data:
    for key in keys:
        wiki_output += '|' + dict_.get(key, '')
    wiki_output += '|\n'
```

There we go...

Comment: This doesn't include the header in the output, and because the set is not sorted, the order in the output is not as expected. try it: https://repl.it/repls/RipeTediousWillet (a closing parenthesis is missing on your third line)

Comment: It's hard to write on a tablet but thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `csv.DictWriter` to handle the formatting, with `StringIO` to collect the input and `defaultdict` to do a bit of creative cheating. Whether or not this is prettier is up for debate.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import DictWriter

output = StringIO()
keys = list(set(key for datum in data for key in datum.keys()))
header = '|'.join('|{}|'.format(key) for key in keys)
output.write(header + '\n')

fields = [''] + keys + [''] # provides empty fields for starting and ending |
writer = DictWriter(output, fields, delimiter = '|')

for row in data:
    writer.writerow(defaultdict(str, **row)) # fills in the empty fields

output.seek(0)
result = output.read()
```

#### How it works

- Create the list of headers by making a set containing all keys that are in any one of your dictionaries.
- Make a DictWriter that uses '|' for its delimiter, to get the pipes between entries.
- Add empty-string headers at the beginning and end, so that the beginning and ending pipes will get written.
- Use a defaultdict to supply the empty beginning and ending values, since they're not in the dictionaries.